# Is there a way to duplicate every value in an excel array?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to duplicate all values in an array in my sheet. I have {1,6,14,15} and I want to output {1,1,6,6,14,14,15,15}. I would like to do this exclusively with functions. I have seen the VSTACK function, which seems very useful, however joining the insider thing seems like a hassle and would not allow this spreadsheet to be usable across other devices easily.

I have tried the CONCAT function, however this simply returns 161415161415 which is not helpful to me. The various alternatives to VSTACK all remove duplicates, which is exactly not what I am looking for. Besides all of those alternatives are lengthy and hard for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: If you don't have `VSTACK`, what *do* you have, and which version(s) do you need it to work with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `EXPAND()` here:

```
=LET(arr,{1,6,14,15},TOROW(IFERROR(EXPAND(arr,2),arr),,1))
```

Note that `2` will define how often you want to duplicate the input.

Comment: I think you mean `EXPAND(arr,2)`, at least for English-language versions of Excel.

Comment: Yes, sorry @JosWoolley, I'm working with Dutch and tested with rows instead.

Comment: @JvdV I tested it but it appends one array after another, it doesn't generate the sequence `{1,1,6,6,14,14,15,15}`. In case you would like to review it, I just copy and pasted to my excel. I see the issue maybe the locale. The following works on my machine (US): `=LET(arr,{1;6;14;15},TOROW(IFERROR(EXPAND(arr,,2),arr)))`

Comment: @DavidLeal, yes locale differences messed with my head. It should be fine now?

Comment: Thanks, @JvdV now it works, I just copy and paste and it works. Good to know how to use the third input argument of `TOROW`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `LET` and `SEQUENCE`:

`=LET(ζ,{1,6,14,15},INDEX(ζ,SEQUENCE(,2*COUNTA(ζ),,0.5)))`

Comment: Good trick, I didn't know `INDEX` can work with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for introducing me to expand! Here's the formula I'm now using. The logic is to first create an array with myCount x myRepeat dimensions populated with 1's. Then, I multiply this array with the array I want repeated using sequence, and then the tocol formula to adjust the range. This works because of how Excel multiplies arrays.

```
=LET(myStart,0,myCount,3,myRepeat,3,myStep,3,EXPAND(SEQUENCE(myCount,,1,0),,myRepeat,1)*SEQUENCE(myCount,,myStart,myStep))
```

{1,1,1;1,1,1;1,1,1} * {0,3,6} = {0,0,0;3,3,3;6,6,6}

```
=LET(myStart,0,myCount,3,myRepeat,3,myStep,3,TOCOL(EXPAND(SEQUENCE(myCount,,1,0),,myRepeat,1)*SEQUENCE(myCount,,myStart,myStep)))
```

Result in the sequence of number starting at 0 (myStart), stepping 3 (myStep), for a count of 3 (myCount), and each step is repeated 3 times (myRepeat).

{0,0,0,3,3,3,6,6,6}

I regularly need this type of array to handle offsets, thanks to this thread I think I've finally found a formula I'm happy with. Thanks!